# How can I get the position of a cursor in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I have to slice the 2 seperate strings according to the position of the cursor in the textinput. And this is what I've tried. (text_box is a textinput property.)

```
text_box = ObjectProperty()

x,y = self.text_box.cursor
```

But then, I found that x, y position is not stable, and keep on changing whenever I click other position.

Is there anyway I can find a stable cursor position information from Kivy?

Also, is there a thing like on_click in textinput instead of on_focus?
(so I can check the cursor position whenever I click the textinput.)

Comment: hmmm as I see in docs The TextInput uses two different coordinate systems:

    (x, y) - coordinates in pixels, **mostly used for rendering on screen**.
    (row, col) - cursor index in characters / lines, used for selection and cursor movement.
So won't using the rows,cols solve Your problem ?

Comment: @Take_Care_ cursor returns col and row. So if I use cursor_col,  and cursor_row, it's the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `text_box.cursor` did not work in `on_focus`

but it works fine in `on_touch_up`.

I am not sure why is that. But at least now I can make it to work.